# How do I add the Sandbox extension for TWIG in the Timber WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, twig, timber

I'm wanting to add the Sandbox extension to evaluate untrusted code using Timber for WordPress (included using composer but I get the same result when using the plugin).

The following (simplified) code results in a fatal error.

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function($twig){

    $filters = array_diff(array_keys($twig->getFilters()), ['function']);

    $policy = new \Twig\Sandbox\SecurityPolicy([], $filters, [], [], []);
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\SandboxExtension($policy, true));
    
    return $twig;
});
```

The error is: "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to register extension "sandbox" as extensions have already been initialized."

Makes no difference if the applied filter is timber/twig or twig_apply_filters.

Is this the incorrect place to add this extension? It seems to only execute when Timber::compile_string is called.

I'm using the latest versions of WordPress and Timber on PHP 7.3.x

Comment: What if you use `add_filter()` instead of `add_action()`?

Comment: @Gchtr thank you for pointing this out - I've adjusted accordingly. Typo on my part, in my code I have it as add_filter(). Incidentally though, add_action() calls add_filter() and so there no difference.

Comment: Okay, I tried out your code, and for me, there is no error. So: where do you add that code snippet, in **functions.php**? Are there other `timber/twig` filters that are being applied?

Comment: @Gchtr, thanks for confirming it works. I managed to get the simplified version of the code working. What was causing the error is that in working out the policy args I was calling `getFilters()` and `getFunctions()`, and these cause extensions to be initialised.

Comment: Good to know, I’m glad you could work it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$twig->getFilters()` causes extensions to be initialised and so can't be used here for this purpose. There is no error and the sandbox extension is registered when this code is removed.